# MysQL Date and Time Manipulation

Tags: mysql, string, date, time

I have a 215 character field, The 16th to the 21st characters are date in the format 030914.

I want to be able to convert that to Date and write it into an adjoining field in the MySQL format yyyy-mm-dd.

I tried String to Date conversion but that is happening only if the date characters are enclosed by 'c' i.e. inverted commas.

Since I have more than 20K records that seems unfeasible.

Characters 22 to 25 is time in the format 1014. This needs to be written into another adjoining field in Time format i.e. hh:mm:ss.

For an experienced MySQL programmer it is a matter of minutes.

Comment: Start by posting what you have tried in order to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### **QUERY**

**Fetching Date -**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(your_column,16,6),"%d%m%y"),
  "%Y-%m-%d")
  FROM your_table;
```

**Fetching Time-**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(your_column,22,4),"%h%i"),
  "%h:%i:%s")
  FROM your_table;
```

**Fetching Both-**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(your_column,16,10),"%d%m%y%h%i"),
  "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s")
  FROM your_table;
```

Here's the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac7e45/10